# Unable to extend OAuthServerBundle controller

Tags: php, symfony, oauth

I'm using Symfony2's OAuth Bundle to authenticate users on my webservice. Everything is working correctly but now I'm interested on extending the fields of the JSon where the token is included. To do that I want to create my own TokenController that extends OAuth Bundle's TokenController. But everytime I'm getting this error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   DAL\WebServiceBundle\Controller\TokenController::__construct() must be
>   an instance of OAuth2\OAuth2, none given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\DALService\app\cache\dev\classes.php on line 2396 and
>   defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\DALService\src\DAL\WebServiceBundle\Controller\TokenController.php
>   line 22

This is my TokenController code:

```
<?php

namespace DAL\WebServiceBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use OAuth2\OAuth2;
use OAuth2\OAuth2ServerException;

use FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Controller\TokenController as BaseTokenController;

class TokenController extends BaseTokenController
{

    public function tokenAction (Request $request)
    {
        $response = parent::tokenAction($request);

        return $response;
    }


}
```

Any idea of what is going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

To extends the TokenController you can overiding it with a compiler pass.

```
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $tokenControllerService = $container->getDefinition('fos_oauth_server.controller.token');
        $tokenControllerService->setClass('YourTokenController');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this:
[How to Define Controllers as Services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html)
and add this to your services.xml/yml

Why **fos_oauth_server.server**?
Because extended controller constructor requires it to work!

## XML:

```
<service id="dal.webservice.bundle.controller.token" class="DAL\WebServiceBundle\Controller\TokenController">
    <argument type="service" id="fos_oauth_server.server" />
</service>
```

## YML:

```
dal.webservice.bundle.controller.token:
        class: DAL\WebServiceBundle\Controller\TokenController 
        arguments:
            server: @fos_oauth_server.server
```

Comment: I tried with both pieces of code and I still get the same error message.

Comment: Try to add this in Your TokenController

`public function __construct(OAuth2 $server)
{
 parent::__construct($server);
}`

Comment: The last thing that comes to my mind is to replace the name of the service:
`id="dal.webservice.bundle.controller.token"`
to:
`id="fos_oauth_server.controller.token"`

Comment: Not working. Anyway, if I come with a solution I'll post it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your services.yml/xml you must define constructor parameters. In ex.:

`your.service:
        class: DAL\WebServiceBundle\Controller\TokenController 
        arguments:
            doctrine: @doctrine //example OFC
        tags:
            - { name: some tag... }`

And here is how to define a controller as service http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem as well, tried all the above and no difference, it just would not let me inject the fos_oauth_server.server service!

But what you can do is extend the default controller class instead of the token controller and then get the fos_oauth_server.server from the service container. Its not an ideal solution imo and I'd prefer to find a way that can extend the fosoauth TokenController class but it does work

```
namespace Acme\ApiBundle\Controller

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class TokenController extends Controller{

  public function tokenAction(Request $request)
  {
    $server = $this->get('fos_oauth_server.server');
    try {
      return $server->grantAccessToken($request);
    } catch (OAuth2ServerException $e) {
      return $e->getHttpResponse();
    }
  }
}
```